# How to prevent steam from starting the game when adding a DLC?

Tags: steam

I was adding free DLC's to some games (like HD Texture packs) and each time I clicked the 'Download' button the game would start, which is very annoying! Why does Valve think that Download == Start game?

**Can I disable this behaviour?**

I already tried turning off 'Allow downloads during gameplay' in the download settings, but didn't work. Since I already have games running while trying to download DLC's for other games (which are not running at that moment).

Comment: If I'm not wrong this is [tag:by-design]... As in very old Valve code?

Comment: Are you saying that the game auto-starts when you install DLC? I've never had that happen, and I have hundreds of DLCs for various games. Can you go into further detail about what exactly happens?

Comment: @TimS. I have the same bug, actually. It's like the OP says: you go to the page of a DLC, click 'Download' (where it otherwise says 'Play' or 'Buy'), and a popup shows of Steam starting the associated game, as if you pressed 'Play' from your library.

Comment: @TimS. Note that this is for free DLC's, these are usually not included when you buy a game together with DLC's, like a complete edition or bundle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your only option is to click the Download button on a Browser instead of Steam. This ends up adding the license to your account instead of directly launching the game.

You get a message similar to "PRODUCT NAME is now registered to your account on Steam.".

Take for example "GRID 2 - Demolition Derby Pack" on the Vivaldi browser:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Seems like a solid workaround, I'll upvote the answer but leave it a little longer open incase there is an in-steam solution.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that you should not click on the '*Yes*' or '*No*' as they will try to do other stuff. Just getting to this point should be enough to trigger any additional download when you have steam running.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. Instead of the "SUCCESS" page, I get a popup saying I need to install Steam before I can install the DLC, and the "Yes, Steam is installed" and "No, I need Steam" options above.

Comment: @Wrigglenite Do you see the license on https://store.steampowered.com/account/licenses/? It might have been silently added to your account.

Comment: Yep, doesn't work. And the license is not added either.