# Is there a way to add free DLC so that it's queued and downloaded without starting the game?

Tags: steam

To download my Steam games and their updates/DLC, I queue them up on my laptop which downloads them to portable HDDs. When I want them on my gaming PC, I copy the games from the portable HDDs (I am working on scripts to automate the process).
Generally, I buy the games and DLC using the browser, either on my laptop or on a different computer altogether (like at work).

When [*Borderlands 2: Commander Lilith and the Fight for Sanctuary*](https://store.steampowered.com/app/872280/Borderlands_2_Commander_Lilith__the_Fight_for_Sanctuary) was released for free, I went to get it, since I have all the other *Borderlands 2* DLC, and wanted to get it ready for whenever I would have the chance to play *Borderlands 2* while waiting for my new system, as my PC at that time was not able to run it.

As I have never been able to add free DLC to the cart via the browser, I booted up the client and added it through that. However, after it had downloaded, *Borderland 2* tried to boot up on my struggling laptop, but I was able to terminate the process.

I'm not sure if this was a one-off with *Borderlands 2* or not, but I would like to be able to get free DLC similar to how I get paid DLC: by adding it to the cart and letting it either trigger as an "update" able to be downloaded, or let it download only when I get around to downloading the base game.

So: is there a way to add free DLC to a game on Steam so that it's queued and/or downloaded, but not let it start the game directly after?

While [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/354012/30879) is almost the same, the issue I'm having is that I already follow the procedure mentioned there for paid DLC. Free DLC, unlike what that answer indicates, does not get registered:

[image: Free DLC]

[image: Notice when Download is clicked]

Hovering over the first button shows a Steam app URL which won't work on a system that doesn't have Steam installed, and the second button goes to [this About page](https://store.steampowered.com/about/).

Also, the URL the Download button here links to is different from what is presented in that answer:

[image: URL]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent steam from starting the game when adding a DLC?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/353995/how-to-prevent-steam-from-starting-the-game-when-adding-a-dlc)

Comment: @Lemon i have edited by question to show how it isn't a duplicate

Comment: Your example is an update, specifically, of which it seems logical it needs the base game to be installed and findable. I take it you have tried other products?

Comment: Could it be browser-dependent? Could you use the url provided by the answer in the other thread to trick Steam into adding it to your profile (e.g. `javascript:addToCart(806920);`)?

Comment: (To come back to my first comment: there is an obvious difference between the kinds of DLC used in both examples: the Endless Space DLC has a Download button without having to check whether or not the base game is installed, whereas for the GRID 2 DLC Steam seemingly has to confirm the existence or installation of the base game before being able to download the 'Pack' (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ds4R2.jpg)). Note that this was in-browser, and I was not logged in).

Comment: @Joachim i did try to use the javascript on [these](https://store.steampowered.com/app/841000) [three](https://store.steampowered.com/app/573546) [dlc](https://store.steampowered.com/app/941170) however they all gave the same message *"Form submission canceled because the form is not connected"* and i did try the javascript yesterday on [this DLC](https://store.steampowered.com/app/743280) which is paid for before i got the game and it did add to the cart but i do notice that the number in the paramater is not the same as what's in the url

Comment: It's strange: the appID for the Endless Space 2 DLC is not even mentioned [here](https://steamdb.info/app/392110/depots/). Anyway, can you try the following: put `steam://nav/console` into your browser's address bar (provided you have the Steam client installed, it should open it up and start the console), type in the following `download_depot 527290 573546 1347014580946892572`, and see if it downloads properly?

Comment: @Joachim before i try it can you explain what the 3 numbers are? the first number looks like the Atelier Firis app id, the second one looks like it's BGM DLC i linked to but i can't guess what the third number is

Comment: It's the manifest ID. Adding this has become necessary where formerly the first two numbers would have been sufficient. Your cautiousness is admirable - you can find the number [here](https://steamdb.info/depot/573546/manifests/) :)

Comment: @Joachim sorry for the wait. i tried the command but it said i didn't have the licences for depot 573546 which seems to be pointing to the DLC as i did check that the game was installed and there was no DRM listed on the game or DLC

Comment: I think this has to do with the Stories DLC having a lot of (localized) sub-packages. I think [here](https://steamdb.info/depot/392117/subs/) you need to find your edition of Endless Space 2, click its SubID, go to 'Depots', click the DepotID of the Stories DLC, and find the right DepotID and manifest ID there.

Comment: Did you try that last thing yet?

Comment: @Joachim yes but i'm not sure if it's not working or if i got the wrong values. i use `download_depot 392110 841000 77368227384698691326` and i get *"manifest not found"*, when i change 841000 (the app ID of the DLC) to 392117 (the Depot ID) i get no message as if it worked but there is no download and i check the DLC page and it doesn't say i own it

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do so would be to uncheck the 'Start playing the game upon completion' checkbox when you are downloading, but that is not always possible (some downloads can only be a few k to unlock something already present in your game files, so the download box just flashes on screen).

Second solution if you can't do the first one:

Have you tried adding this DLC to your account (and starting its download) via the Steam Mobile application?

[image]
[image]

With it you can queue a download on your PC, and it will not start it (its use is usually to start a download while you are away from your PC). So it shouldn't boot the game upon completion.